# The part of post disappears after "<" mark without space

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, editor, user-interface

[image: Bug of not stripped tag]I include the bug here in [this post](https://cs.stackexchange.com/revisions/60275/1) (visible in edit)

Comment: I agree this looks like a bug, but in which situtation do we have `<` that should not be in code or math environments? Since there is a colorful and helpful box, I don't think newcomers should be too confused.

Comment: When posting bug reports, it's usually best to include a screenshot so the post can be made sense of later.

Comment: @Raphael I disagree with "support" tag, this is a bug, maybe not that important, but still, what next?

Comment: @Oded changed tags which means he as dev on SO's payroll does not think this is a bug. Little to be done. FWIW, since this is *documented behaviour* I'd agree it's not a bug. If you want it changed, it's a feature request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<` is also the starting character of any HTML tag - which a subset of is allowed in markdown.

As such - it isn't escaped by the parser - and your browser thinks that *everthing* after `<` (until a `>` is reached) is a tag. So isn't shown on the page.

Solution? When posting math, use [math formatting](http://www.math.harvard.edu/texman/), as in [the edited post](https://cs.stackexchange.com/revisions/60275/7).

Comment: I am rather aware of the HTML, and please take in mind that 'script' tag is stripped away,'a' is stripped, attributes are stripped away, so only usable options are already put in another form to editor and MathJax available, but not existing tags are not stripped although they are parsed anyway. So no benefits but when user comes unaware of that the part of the post just disappears. I was the one who corrected it, so I do not need support - I think this is a bug, like the one with broken MathJax, and MathJax preview in review queue so this is either bug or this post is to be deleted.

Comment: "your browser thinks that everthing after < [...] is a tag. So isn't shown on the page." -- inspecting the page source it's clear that the missing text does not even make it to the browser. It goes missing somewhere in your pipeline.

Comment: Yes, I have checked, @Raphael is right, no sign of it.